# C#, HtmlUnit JavaScript Support

Tags: c#, .net, htmlunit, nhtmlunit

I am trying to read a test page using NHtmlUnit.WebClient. The page is keep asking to enable JavaScript. Am I missing something?

My Code:

```
var client = new NHtmlUnit.WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17); 
client.Options.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
client.WaitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

client.Options.ThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode = false;
client.AjaxController = new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController();                                                                
var page = (HtmlPage)client.GetPage(googleCaptchaUrl);
var pageStr = page.AsXml().ToString();
```

Comment: disabling `ThrowExceptionOnScriptError` prevents you from seeing other errors, that could be the reason

Comment: I removed the 'ThrowExceptionOnScriptError' - there is no errors on page.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could use latest HtmlUnit proper and provide your complete case, please read https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/htmlunit/src/site/xdoc/submittingJSBugs.xml

Comment: I am using version 2.15.0 (got it two days ago from nuget). I changed the Browser version to: (BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11) and I managed to get the page! One thing though - the process of getting the page is very very slow (15 min)